# How do I link my Stack Exchange profile to an apptivate.ms profile?

Tags: support, status-completed

I have a tresktir account with Stack Overflow and wanted to connect it to my apptivate account so I could give apps votes and comments.

**Edit:**
I logged in using Google when first signed up for apptivate.
Then I created a Stack Overflow account using a different account.
So the reputation I have is with this other account.

Comment: [This page](http://apptivate.ms/login) didn't work for you?

Comment: @Robert That didn't work though. I updated the post.

Comment: Try adding the Google account that you used for Apptivate to your logins on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your help. I did that before I posted the question.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.  Shall we keep dancing like this? :P

Comment: What's the link to the SO profile associated with your Apptivate account? That is, log into Stack Overflow with the same credentials you use on Apptivate and then give me the link.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/200479/trekstir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged your accounts, so you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!